# Brief Macro issue

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a macro which opens and edits workbooks for me. It adds in a column (A) and then formats the titles of cells A1, B1, C1 and D1.

After this, I want to add the same date in each A cell conditional on if there is a text in the corresponding cell in column B - RC[1].

Does anybody know what (`Wkb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A250") = "31/12/2014"`) of the macro should be or if I have done it completely wrong?

Maybe I need a loop?

```
Sub test()
    Dim MyPath          As String
    Dim MyFile          As String
    Dim Wkb             As Workbook
    Dim Cnt             As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'MyPath = "G:\SHARED\Style Research\Portfolios - Macro Test"
    MyPath = Range("D6").Value

    If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then MyPath = MyPath & "\"

    MyFile = Dir(MyPath & "*.xls")

    Cnt = 0
    Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
        Cnt = Cnt + 1
        Set Wkb = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFile)
        Wkb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").EntireColumn.Insert
        Wkb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A250") = "31/12/2014"
        'Wkb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "DD/MM/YYYY"
        Wkb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = "Date"
        Wkb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1") = "Identifier"
        Wkb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C1") = "Name"
        Wkb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D1") = "%"

        Wkb.Close savechanges:=True
        MyFile = Dir
    Loop

    If Cnt > 0 Then
        MsgBox "Finito", vbExclamation
    Else
        MsgBox "Error!", vbExclamation
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You definitely need a loop this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A loop will do it for you.

Replace

```
 Wkb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A250") = "31/12/2014"
```

with

```
Dim i as Integer
For i = 1 To 250
    Dim r As Range
    Set r =  Wkb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i, "RC" & i)
    For Each Cell In r.Cells
        If Cell.Value <> "" Then
            Wkb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value = "31/12/2014"
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next
```

The following code will basically loop from 1 to 250. i is the counter.
For each i increment, the code will check each cell (`For Each Cell`) from your desired range of `B-RC[i]`.

If the cell value is not empty, it will proceed to by adding the date to the corresponding `Range("A"&i)` and it will stop looking for values in the desired range, exit using `Exit For` and move to on to the next `i`.

Comment: thanks.. this has helped fix it.                                                        I have also added 'dim i as variant' and then 'dim cell'.

Comment: I'll vote you up when I get enough rep! One more q... what should I dim cell?

Comment: You don't need to dim cell, cell is automatically initiated as part of the for each loop.

Comment: I agree, but it brings around the error message saying "variable not defined"?

Comment: @Ewldh20 Try it now. I guess the With was provoking it.

Comment: Thanks all, still asking for cell to be defined! It's not liking this ha.

Comment: @Ewldh20 yes the For Each defines the cell. If you have further questions, I *strongly* suggest you check out an advanced tutorial and google, most of your questions should be answered there ;)

Comment: Happy for you it works! Can you show me a printscreen of your VBA IDE. I have never come across a situation where I needed to define a cell.